# function template partial specialization 'swap<T>' is not allowed

Tags: c++, templates

I'm struggling with templates. The following compiles for me just fine:

```
//foo.h
class foo {
public:
    template <typename T>
    void swap(T* values, uint8_t offset)
    {
        T swp = values[offset];
        values[offset] = values[offset + 1];
        values[offset + 1] = swp;
    }
};
```

This does not:

```
//foo.h
class foo {
public:
    template <typename T>
    void swap(T* values, uint8_t offset);
};

//foo.cpp
template <typename T>
void foo::swap<T>(T* values, uint8_t offset)
{
    T swp = values[offset];
    values[offset] = values[offset + 1];
    values[offset + 1] = swp;
}
```

I get the error message

```
error: function template partial specialization 'swap<T>' is not allowed
```

I don't know what that means so I'm unclear on how to proceed. Thanx in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file?rq=1 for more information on template definitions in .cpp files.

Comment: @rwols Sure you can, see the link in the above comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `<T>`:

```
template <typename T>
void foo::swap(T* values, uint8_t offset)
{
    // …
}
```

That syntax is for template specialization.

Also, you will most likely want your template definitions in the header file, see [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/3425536).

Comment: Maybe worth to mention that templates shall be defined in the header http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file?rq=1

Comment: @Christophe Added.

Comment: That did the trick. Apparently of all the things I tried, that wasn't one of them. I'm still working my noodle around the concept, but this is a start at least. Thanx.